# How to send e-mail to customers using quick campaing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, dynamics-crm

I have a question/problem. I want sent email to my clients using quick campaing. But in those emails I want to put some information for only this customer.
For example:

First customer - A - have a information: login: only_for_A and password: only_for_A

Second customer - B - have a information: login: only_for_B and password: only_for_B
etc.

But the passwords are in Excel file.

Is there any possibility to automatically add login and password to email?

Comment: You would need to put the necessary information in a database or maybe an xml file, then write a function that would include the said information, that being said, I wouldn't know where to start exactly with regards to writing it.

Comment: I think the Dynamics-CRM tags were relevant!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for mail merge. Here's a walkthrough:

[Use mail merge to distribute merged e-mail messages](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/use-mail-merge-to-distribute-merged-e-mail-messages-HP005187257.aspx)

In the spreadsheet, the information for each customer would need to be in its own row (including login and password), along with email address. Then you would create the letter in Word, connect to the spreadsheet as a data source and merge to email. Each row in the spreadsheet would generate its own email which contains the information for that person.

Comment: Can I do this witch Dynamics CRM?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the information into Dynamics-CRM for it to be included in your email.

You need to create the username and password attributes in your customer (account or contact?) entity, this would be done by customising that entity.

Then you'd need to import it from the excel spreadsheet. CRM can do imports from Excel but getting it to update the correct customer records would be difficult, I think you'd need the GUIDs for each CRM customer in the excel spreasheet so that CRM could make the connection. The alternative is to write code that accesses the Dynamics CRM webservice, search for each customer and set the custom fields.

Once you have the data in CRM it should be fairly easy to create a quick campaign and add the fields in to the body of the email, just as you would for the customer name or other details.

The alternative would be to export from Dynamics-CRM into Excel, join up the data and do a much simpler mailmerge from there, but this would stop the emails and their responses being tracked, which is kinda the whole point of CRM.